# Javascript For loop autoincreament is not working

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to run For loop in JavaScript but it is not working for me. Auto increment value is not working I tried to check by altering:

```
alert('add_fname_'+i);
```

but it is giving `"add_fname_0"` as output

```
function checkadditionals(){
    var tvrs = Number(document.getElementById('additional_travellers').value);

    for ( var i = 0; i < tvrs; i++) {
      console.log('add_fname_' + i);
      document.getElementById('add_fname_'+i).required = true;
      document.getElementById('add_lname_'+i).required = true;
      document.getElementById('add_dob_'+i).required = true;
      document.getElementById('relation_'+i).required = true;
      document.getElementById('pre_exe_'+i).required = true;
    }
}

<select onchange="checkadditionals()" class="form-control" id="additional_travellers" name="additional_travellers">
  <option value="0">None</option> 
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option> 
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what is the value of `tvrs`?

Comment: What's the value of tvrs? Jinx @Dan O

Comment: I mentioned about that is coming from form select

Comment: tvrs = ? 1, 2,3,4 ?

Comment: Could you provide the HTML with the element whose id is `additional_travellers`

Comment: <select onchange="checkadditionals()" class="form-control" id="additional_travellers" name="additional_travellers">
<option value="0">None</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select>

Comment: Do you see any error message in the console in the developer tools of your browser? If you only see `add_fname_0` as alert, then the following code most likely results in an error.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with your `for`, the problem is probably your `tvrs` value is 0, so the for loop never starts, cause `i` isn't less than `tvrs`.
please, edit your question and add the `checkadditionals()` function to be more clear